# Why is the default shell in Debian 7 bash?

Tags: debian, shell

As per [documentation](https://packages.debian.org/stable/shells/dash), `dash` should be the default shell in Debian Wheezy, however when I open up a terminal and check the `SHELL` variable, it points to `/bin/bash`. Since this is a fresh install, and I have not made any changes, why is this not pointing to `/bin/dash`? Or is the default shell stored or pointed to by some other variable?

Comment: What makes you think that dash is the default shell?

Comment: @jasonwryan *Since it executes scripts faster than bash, and has fewer library dependencies (making it more robust against software or hardware failures), **it is used as the default system shell on Debian systems.*** From the Wheezy dash [package page](https://packages.debian.org/stable/shells/dash).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell), the default `/bin/sh` shell is dash, but the default *interactive* shell is bash:

> The default interactive shell is bash (it's defined in /etc/adduser.conf then copied to the user profile, see chsh(1) manpage).

System scripts with the POSIX shebang will be run by dash, but when you--the user--open an interactive shell, it will be `/bin/bash` unless you elect to change it.

Comment: How/where do I check for the default non-interactive shell?

Comment: @AsheeshR Look in `/bin/`, you'll see the link: `sh -> dash`...

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you open `/etc/default/useradd` you find that `SHELL=/bin/sh` so that any user account created with `useradd` will have dash as their default shell!

Comment: @JosephR. that sounds like a bug.

Comment: @jasonwryan Good point. I'm currently swamped but I'll report it as soon as I have time and post a link here. In the meantime, feel free to report it if I haven't.